# Client side cache versus server side cache

Tags: php, javascript, caching, client-side, server-side

I am working on a project that requires 40 different weekly articles/content to be shown based on the week the user is in. This is what has lead me to my question and research: For such a long duration as this which is a better approach: 1. Cache on the client side or 2. Cache on the server side?

I currently have a cache.class built using PHP and can reference that to create a server side cache but I'm worried about performance and the flip side I have a java script to cache the local data like the date entered by the user to start the 40 week countdown.

I'm getting back into the world of PHP, JScript, etc coming from a stand alone app production environment so please take it easy on me if the questions seem a bit rudimentary.

Thank you,
-Chad

Answer (score 0):

I think best way is to set up nginx to cache some urls. It would be good decision and it works really fast.